# Setting a value of a TextArea inside a WebBrowser Control Error

Tags: c#

So there is the following textarea:

```
<textarea class="profile" name="message"></textarea>
```

and I want to set the value of this textarea using code in C#. When I use the following code

```
 private void messageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     webBrowser1.Document
     .GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
     .GetElementsByName("message")[0]
     .SetAttribute("value", "Something");

  }
```

I get the error:

```
Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.

Parameter name: index
```

How can I set the value of this textarea?

Comment: Are you sure this error message belongs on this code?

Comment: Why don't you use an server control and use an id to directly set the value? (I guess the code is from a webpage.)

Answer (score 2):

This would happen when `GetElementsByName()` returns an empty `HtmlElementCollection`.

Comment: @ SLaks so does that mean a text area with "message" name doesn't exist?

Comment: @ SLaks: So is there a way to set the value to any textarea found?

Comment: @user1999321: Look at the previous line (and use a loop)

Comment: Can you give and example @ SLaks